# Which Development Method use for a Website Development?

Tags: project-management, agile

Which is  a good Project Managment Method to Develop a Website?
XP? The Waterfall Model?

Comment: You need to provide more information. What is the team size? How long wil the project last? How accessible are the business stakeholders and customers? These and related questions determine the project management method best suited for you.

Comment: The question is similar to what hair style is best for men?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agile/XP would be best.

Waterfall would be the worst choice in my opinion.

Comment: Thank you for the help, i will use XP for my projects

Answer (score 2):

Anything but waterfall....

But keep in mind that saying you are agile and being really agile are two different things.

For agile to really work over an extended period one has to also be doing several technical things well.

http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2010/02/20/nice-process-but-what-about-the-engineering-bits.aspx

http://davybrion.com/blog/2010/02/youll-never-get-sustainable-progress-for-free/

Comment: -1 for your "Anything but waterfall..." statement. Waterfall may be the best method if it is what fits the needs of the client.

Comment: Good point Jeffrey.  Perhaps a little to absolute.  However, I think you can give the client what they want without following waterfall yourself even if they are used to that.

Comment: There is absolutely no reason to ever be absolute.

Comment: @Jeffrey-Hines HeHe... Good one. :-)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on who the customer is. If you are your own customer, then definately Agile.

If your aren't your own customer then you will have to negotiate with your customer on your development method. If your customer wants a fixed bid project and a hard deadline, then you will be best served by the waterfall method.

If your customer is willing to be an active participant in the development process and doesn't have a hard deadline and fixed budget then you could do Agile/XP.

Answer (score 1):

It always depends on the type of the website you are developing, how many developers you got, what is the timeline, expectation for delivery time. But definitely Agile or prototype-iterative method will work fine for website development. To complete the development in different phases, and enhancing in the chucks, as an when identifying the strong and weak areas.

As well you can check the factors like target audience, maximum used sectors of the site and prioritize the development of those pieces first.

Always consider to go with standard framework, that will make life easier in long run with the future developments.

Answer (score 1):

I find that waterfall fits some web **site** projects fairly well.  Get the requirements, wireframe a design, do the graphic design, convert the graphic designs to HTML/CSS/JS,  then fill out the content of the site. Client signs off at each stage. If the site is large the last stage ("fill out content") is probably more work than all the preceding ones and you'll want to use iterative methodologies for it, not waterfall.

Waterfall tends to *not* fit web **applications** very well. Those are software, treat them as such.

Comment: I'm not sure that I agree with your distinction between site & application; to me, they are both applications of varying scopes. But +1 for your 1st paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

**Use waterfall! But:**

1. Set duration of the project to 1 month.
2. Then repeat this project until customer is happy!

Comment: And the customer is never happy so you'll keep on going for ever.

Comment: Hasan, I'm sorry you have such an experience. Can't say all of my customers are happy, but most of them are. Anyway, having customer unhappy has it's good sides: you are always employed and (provided you have negotiated the contract right) always have income.