# Languages and Tools for Web programming

Tags: language-agnostic

I am wanting to start Web Development and I was wondering what languages I would want to learn and what (if at all possible) free tools I would want to use.

Comment: @Pierreten: OK, i want to make websites and web apps. That work?

Comment: No.  You just restated your question.

Comment: @ Pierreten: ok sorry, what do you mean by narrow it down? I want to do client side stuff, not server side. if that's what you mean

Comment: @Mark: Make it more specific. Your question is too vague and ambitious (not that I think this should be closed, but that is the description of a close reason...)

Comment: Ok, never mind Greg answered my question.  Thanks though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Languages:

- HTML
- Javascript plus jQuery
- for server side, anything from C++ to Ruby to ASP.NET
- PHP

Tools:

- Firebug
- Internet Explorer / Firefox / Chrome / Opera
- Text editor (vim / emacs)

(please add to the above lists, answer CW)

Answer (score -1):

Client side: see http://wsc.opera.com/

Server side: use pretty much any language you are comfortable with (I tend towards Perl with the Catalyst framework)

Answer (score -1):

Some links:

- [A good resource for an overview of web technologies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596214/a-good-resource-for-an-overview-of-web-technologies)
- [Are There Any Other Web Programming Languages That Can Be Used Without A Framework Aside From PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2583494/are-there-any-other-web-programming-languages-that-can-be-used-without-a-framewor)
- [What web frameworks and languages have the lowest development time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2570160/what-web-frameworks-and-languages-have-the-lowest-development-time)
- [How to choose the right web application framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536054/how-to-choose-the-right-web-application-framework)
- [Which Development Method use for a Website Development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2344508/which-development-method-use-for-a-website-development)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72394/what-should-a-developer-know-before-building-a-public-web-site

I found these in a few minutes of searching [Newest <kbd>web-development</kbd> Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=web-development&sort=newest&pagesize=50).